# Alternative of IN in SQL to execute it in less time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wrote a query but I want to know if this execution time will be slow or fast?  Can we use any alternative to `IN` since it is used 4 times in such a small query.
Can we have a better way to write this query ? Moreover I am  confused because the someone wants to query it with large number of `ep_et_id` and the way I wrote this is no where have a place to mention the `ep_et_id`

The below query fetches 74133 results in 14.55 secs in direct Postgres call. But I believe this will take more time if I call it from the webpage.

```
select lp, ob_id
from ob_in
where ob_id in (select ob_id
                from ob_for_e
                where ep_et_id in (select ep_et_id 
                                   from rrts rep
                                   left join rrts_inf rinf on rep.rrts_id = rinf.rrts_id
                                   where rrts_type in ('FR','IN')
                                   and rinf.status in('V')))
```

The tables I am using here are `ob_in`, `ob_for_e`, `rrts` , `rrts_inf`
The location point `lp` are in table `ob_in` and I put many `IN` to fetch IDs from the table to apply the final condition on table `rrts_inf` for type `FR` , `IN`  and Status with `V`

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: But I believe this will take more time if I call it from the webpage.` ← Why do you think that? Can you test that theory? If so what did you observe.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but: the condition `where rinf.status in (..)` turns your `left join` back into an inner join

Comment: Replace in with exists, exists are generally faster than in however it depends on the result sets.

Comment: I would probably join the tables in the sub-select rather than nesting the IN conditions and then use a single EXISTS condition on the outer-most level. Something like this: http://dpaste.com/32AWMGM

Comment: @Igor I have not tested it on Web page but since it  took 15 secs in execution on testing environment so its my belief it will take more time from web page (production)  and more worrisome is that after 29 sec there is a timeout error occurrence

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I ran your query , Its strange ,my query gives ` Total query runtime: 13 secs 851 msec. 74143 rows affected.` and your query gives  `Total query runtime: 12 secs 530 msec. 74088 rows affected.` The results are different

Comment: Because my query does use an outer join on `rrts_inf` and your query does not